# Sample dataset and Sample dashboard that uses SAQL

Tags: analytics-cloud, einstein-analytics, saql

I am trying to use SAQL for my dashboar. But when I specify filter or group in SAQL, the dataset fails to load the bar charts.
Below is my step I am using

```
    "steps": {
        "device_type_time_Day_event_1": {
            "isFacet": true,
            "start": null,
            "query": {"pigql":"q = load \"sample_data_5_26\"; q = group q by 'device_type'; q = foreach q generate 'device_type' as 'device_type', 'event' as 'event', count() as 'count'",
                "measures": [
                    [
                        "count",
                        "*"
                    ]
                ],
                "groups": ["device_type"
                ]
            },
            "extra": {
                "chartType": "vbar"
            },
            "selectMode": "single",
            "useGlobal": true,
            "em": "ad_data_5_26",
            "type": "aggregate",
            "isGlobal": false
        }
```

I am finding it hard to figure whats wrong with the SAQL.

1. Where can I find the salesforce wave dashboard logs?
2. In the SAQL dev document dashborad JSON reference document, it seems an 'airline' dataset being used. Can I get the sample and the corresponding dashboard for my reference?

Comment: Are you part of the pilot? If so, I'd expect you'd be asking this question in the pilot area. I don't believe SAQL is enabled in orgs yet unless you're enrolled in the pilot. Please correct me if I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 - There are no logs, however you can see the transactions taking place by going into Chrome --> Inspect Element ---> Network ---> Remote --> Headers OR Response. Do this on the dashboard, and when you are at the screen refresh the page so it pulls in all of the information on the calls.

2 - I have a copy of the dataset here: http://www.andrewprice.me/blog/2015/4/5/uploading-a-dataset-into-salesforce-analytics - US Airlines Ontime Dataset

3 - I believe this isn't working for you for a couple of reasons: The query isn't formed correctly , and the information isn't added to the compact query which is below the Pigql query. I believe your query should look like this:

```
"steps": {
    "device_type_time_Day_event_1": {
        "isFacet": true,
        "start": null,
        "query": {"pigql":"q = load \"sample_data_5_26\"; q = group q by ('device_type',event); q = foreach q generate 'device_type' as 'device_type', 'event' as 'event', count() as 'count' ; q = limit q 2000;",
            "measures": [
                [
                    "count",
                    "*"
                ]
            ],
            "groups": [
              "device_type",
              "event"
            ]
        },
        "extra": {
            "chartType": "vbar"
        },
        "selectMode": "single",
        "useGlobal": true,
        "em": "ad_data_5_26",
        "type": "aggregate",
        "isGlobal": false
    }
```

Comment: Is it always required to mention the groupings and measures in Compact form for the groupings and measures written in SAQL queries ?